# Manually re-render / reload a-frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, virtual-reality, aframe

I have an a-scene embedded into a div container like so:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <a-scene embedded>
      <a-sky src="img/vr/act1.jpg" rotation="0 -130 0"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
</div>
```

in css:

```
 a-scene { display: block; width: 500px !important; height: 500px !important; }
```

But the problem is, because the div is hidden at the start, when i unhide it, the a-scene's contents width and height is 0,0. Im trying to reload the aframe tied to a click event when the `div` container unhides itself.

I looked at the docs and there is the `reload` method, and i tried this but its not working:

```
document.querySelector('a-scene').reload();
```

i get the following error in the console :

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...).reload is not a function
at <anonymous>:1:35
```

strangely, `enterVR`, which is also listed as a method in the docs works with the same syntax. So if i were to do `enterVR` and `exitVR`in succession, the a-frame will actually display as what i want it to

So im not sure what im doing wrong.

using a-frame 0.7

Comment: I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:

```
location.reload(true);
scene.enterVR();
```

Comment: what do you mean by location?